# How to modify a value by selection in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to change the value of my progress bar.

```
var progressBar = d3.select("#current").append("input")
    .attr("class","loading")
    .attr("data-width","135")
    .attr("value","0");
```

When I do this :

> progressBar.select("input").attr("value","5");

The value is not changed. What should I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you already selected your input and bound it to the variable progressBar. So this piece of code you showed:

```
progressBar.select("input").attr("value", "5")
```

Effectively means:

```
d3.select("#current").select("input").select("input").attr("value", "5")
```

You're essentially selecting for an input within the input you created which doesn't exist.

---

Your code should work fine by simply using:

```
progressBar.attr('value', 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var progressBar = d3.select("#current").append("input")
    .attr("class","loading")
    .attr("data-width","135")
    .val(0);
```